# How to find portlets added on a particular page in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet

How can I find which portlets are added on a particular Liferay page?

For Example:
I have three pages: *Welcome*, *Wiki* and *Search*.

Now all these pages have portlets added on them and some of them are instanceable portlets (like web-content display and iframe portlets).

Now I want to pass some information in the form of request parameters to the `iframe-portlet` on the `Search page` from the `Welcome page`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have found two ways to do this:

1. If you want to find the portlets on the same page in which your portlet is added then, you can make use of `themeDisplay` object available to your portlet or JSP:

   ```
   // In JSP
   List<String> portletIdList = themeDisplay.getLayoutTypePortlet().getPortletIds();

   // In portlet class
   ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) portletRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
   List<String> portletIdList = themeDisplay.getLayoutTypePortlet().getPortletIds();
   ```
2. If you want to find the portlets on some different page, then you should know three things viz; `friendly-url`, `groupId` and whether this page is a `public-page` or `private-page` of the Site (or Community), so here is the code:

   ```
   // 101543 is the SiteId, if it is a public-page then "false" and "/search" is the friendlyURL
   LayoutTypePortlet layoutTypePortlet = LayoutTypePortletFactoryUtil.create(LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getFriendlyURLLayout(101543, false, "/search"));
   List<String> portletIdList = layoutTypePortlet.getPortletIds();
   ```

The `portletIdList` contains the portletIds complete with their instanceIds. So now from the list you can just filter out the `iframe-portlet` on the `/search` page by using `com.liferay.portal.util.PortletKeys.IFRAME` and you will get something like `48_INSTANCE_rPv9`.

Comment: Still helpful after all these years :-) I've been struggling with programmatically Primefaces "update" for full portlet component IDs and now use ...getPortletDisplay().getNamespace() + ...