# Dynamicaly Create actionURL to Instanceable Portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I've been working on a programmatic creation of Liferay actionUrls in the `MVCPortlet` Controller.
So far, I have successfully managed to create a working link to the action of another portlet,
placed in another page (`Layout` in Liferay terms) by using this code:

```java
LiferayPortletResponse rr = PortalUtil.getLiferayPortletResponse( response);

Layout layout = ... // I manage to get the correct one using  LayoutLocalServiceUtil

LiferayPortletURL ddUrl = rr.createActionURL("portlet_WAR_name") ;

if(Validator.isNotNull(layout)){
    // Setting info to the other portlet
    ddUrl.setPlid(layout.getPlid());

    // Setting the action Name
    ddUrl.setParameter(ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME, "actionFunctionNameOf_MVCPortlet");

    // adding any action-related params
    ddUrl.setParameter("someParam1", ...) );
    ddUrl.setParameter("someParam2", ...) );

    return ddUrl;
}
```

My problem is that this will not work on an **instanceable** Portlet.

Is there some parameter I could add, to make this url link to `-any-` instance of the target Portlet?

Or do I need to know the `instanceId` of the target Portlet? If so, how can I set this to the `LiferayPortletURL` instance?

Thanx in advance, any help would be really appreciated

**P.S.: I'm working with Liferay 6.1 GA1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the portletid to the **instanceable** portlet id:

```
String portletId = (String) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_ID);
ddUrl.setPortletId(portletId);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this way I can get my portlet's PORTLET_ID, not the Portlet I want to link to. I'll still vote you up for the hint on .setPortletId() method

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found a way, so I'm sharing:

```java
LiferayPortletResponse rr = PortalUtil.getLiferayPortletResponse( response);

// I get the correct layout using  LayoutLocalServiceUtil
Layout layout = ... ;

LiferayPortletURL ddUrl = rr.createActionURL("portlet_WAR_name");

if(layout != null) {

    // Setting info to the other portlet
    ddUrl.setPlid(layout.getPlid());

    // Setting the action Name
    ddUrl.setParameter(ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME, "actionFunctionNameOf_MVCPortlet");

    //Finding the full portletId of the instanceable Portlet
    LayoutTypePortlet layoutTypePortlet =
        LayoutTypePortletFactoryUtil.create(
            LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getFriendlyURLLayout(
                themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId(), 
                false, "page_friendly_url")
        );

    List<String> portletIdList = layoutTypePortlet.getPortletIds();

    for(String prtId : portletIdList){
        if(prtId.contains("portlet_WAR_name")){
            ddUrl.setPortletId(prtId);
        }
    }

    // adding any action-related params
    ddUrl.setParameter("someParam1", ...) );
    ddUrl.setParameter("someParam2", ...) );

    return ddUrl;
}
```

Thanx to Tony Rad for the [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13483571/468763) on `setPortletId`.

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827415/how-to-find-portlets-added-on-a-particular-page-in-liferay) very useful.